Excel - If any row with X value in the first cell contains Y value in specific column, return Y value
I have an excel file where I keep control of my coin collection. In that file I have 2 sheets: coins per country (image 1) and coins per country+year (image 2).
Image 1

Image 2

I wanted to connect the two sheets so that when I introduce data on the "coins per country+year" sheet, the "coins per country" could assume that I have that coin (value) for that country, regardless of the year. In other words, if any row (any year) for "Portugal" has a 2€ coin, the "coins per country" table will assume that I already have a 2€ coin for Portugal. After browsing a bit I tried the VLOOKUP function, but without the desired output.
Anyone has any idea how to achieve this?

It's spelled BitCoin not Belgium ...

The simplest thing to do would be to simplify your input table to have Country|Year|Denomination|Count as columns.  Once you have this structure, it's an easy step to use a Pivot Table for your output.

The two tables are on the same sheet for simplicity.
The formula in B2
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS($N$2:$R$13,MATCH(B$1,$N$1:$R$1,0)),$L$2:$L$13=$A2),0))>0,1,0)
drag to the right and then down.


A Two-Way Lookup
=LET(dcoins,B1:I1,dcountry,A2:A5,sdata,Sheet2!A1:J21,
    scoins,DROP(TAKE(sdata,1),,2),
    scountry,DROP(TAKE(sdata,,1),1),
    svals,DROP(sdata,1,2),
    s,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(dcountry),COLUMNS(dcoins),LAMBDA(r,c,
        SUM(FILTER(XLOOKUP(INDEX(dcoins,c),scoins,svals),
        scountry=INDEX(dcountry,r))))),
    r,IF(s>0,1,0),
    r)


Replace the bottom-most r with any of the other variables to see what it holds.
Replace the bottom-most 0 with "" if preferable.


